# Matching *ptr = value with coccinelle

Tags: c, coccinelle

I want to match

```
*ptr=value;
```

in a C code and then replace it by

```
CHECK_PTR(ptr)
*ptr=value;
```

CHECK_PTR() is a macro that check if ptr is not null

I write a Coccinelle script to do the work

```
@rule1@
type T;
T* ptr;
expression E;
@@
-\*ptr=E;
+CHECK_PTR(ptr)
+*ptr=E;
```

But this doesn't work because of the star operator.
Here i used the backslash to escape the * however this didn't give any result

Could you help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem few days ago and this is the answer to your problem

"Column 0 is different than the others.  Just pu a space in front of your *
and everything will be fine.

This problem commonly arises for parentheses.  For example if you want to
add a new last argument for a function, you might say:

```
f(27
+ , 145
)
```

In this case, Coccinelle can detect the potential problem and will
complain.  Because ( | and ) in column 0 are used for a disjunction (a set
oo different possible matches and transformations.  For *, though it
doesn't know which you want."
Julia Lawall